# Quasi-Monte-Carlo vs. variable dimensionality?

Tags: montecarlo

I've been looking through the Matlab documention on using quasi-random sampling of N-dimensional unit cubes.  This represents a problem with N stochastic parameters.  Based on the fact that it is a unit cube, I presume that I need to use the inverse CDF of each parameter to map from the [0,1] domain to the value range of each parameter.

I would like to try this on a problem for which I now use Monte Carlo.  Unfortunately, the problem I'm analyzing does not have a fixed number of dimensions.  For each instantiation of the problem, I generate a variable number of widgets (say) using a Poisson distribution.  Only after that do I randomly generate the parameters for each widget.  That whole process yields one instance of the problem to be analyzed, so the number of parameters varies from one instance to the next.

Is this kind of problem still amenable to Quasi-Monte-Carlo?

Answer (score 0):

What I used once was to get highest possible dimension of the problem `d`, generate Sobol sequence in `d` and use whatever number of points necessary for a particular sampling. I would say it helped somewhat...

Comment: Thanks, Severin. Can you please elaborate on what you meant by using whatever number of points necessary for a particular sampling?  Do you mean that you simply ignored some of the dimensions (thus projecting the points onto a lower dimensional subspace)? I suspect that this would interfere with the desirable spacing and uniformity properties of the quasi-random sampling, which brings into question whether it is worthwhile pursuing over plain old Monte Carlo.

Comment: @user36800 yes, it means that if highest dimension was 40 (mine was actually infinite, but I had some reasonable upper limit), you generate Sobol in 40d, and if you particular event require 30, you use first 30d out of 40d and go to sampling next event. `this would interfere with the desirable spacing and uniformity properties of the quasi-random sampling` yes, result was less bang than we expected. `which brings into question whether it is worthwhile pursuing over plain old Monte Carlo.` you have to decide for yourself

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying.  I'd like to leave the answer as unaccepted for a while longer to see if someone responds with an approach that doesn't compromise on the desirable properties of quasi-randomness.  Though I'm not holding my breath.  The whole idea of uniformly good spacing becomes foggy to me when it involves Euclidean distances over spaces of different dimensionality.

Comment: @user36800 ok. Also would be interesting to try if you have a MINIMUM guaranteed dimension. This could be sampled via QMC, and anything above would be plain old MC.

Comment: The number of widgets is Poisson distributed, i.e., goes from 0 to infinity. I could crudely approximate this with a triangle function. However, there are actually a number of widget types, each with different distribution parameters. Once the number of each widget type is stochastically determined, then each widget type has 3 stochastically generated parameters.  Overall, the minimum is zero dimensions, though that is highly unlikely. It's really complicated to visualize a good triangular approximation to the overall number of widgets when each widget type has a different Poisson distribution

Comment: @user36800 Ah, I see. Well, it is interesting question for me, though for some time how to properly mix QMC and just MC. For example, what would be meaning of the computational (and statistical) error. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I might just go with MC. I made a mistake in my last comment. I have a large number of widget types. For each, the quantity of widgets have different distributions. I determine the number of widgets for each type, then for each widget of each type, there are 3 stochastic parameters. Fingers crossed that someone will propose a way to deal with the variable number of stochastic parameters without compromising on QMC (but not holding my breath)

Answer (score 0):

From talking to a much smarter colleague, we need to consider the various combinations of widget counts for each widget type.  For example, if we have 2 of widget type#1, 4 of widget type #2, 1 of widget type #3, etc., that constitutes one combination.  QMC can be applied to that one combination. We are assuming that number of widget#i is independent of the number of widget#j for i<>j, so the probability of each combination is just the product of p(2 widgets of type#1), p(4 widgets of type#2), p(1 widget of type#3), etc. The individual probabilities are easy to get from their Poisson distributions (or their flat distributions, or *whatever* distribution is being used).  If there are N widget types, this is just a joint PMF in N-space. This probability is then used to weight the QMC result for that particular combination.  Note that even when the exactly combination is nailed down, QMC is still needed because there each widget is associated with 3 stochastic parameters.